# Define a condition in a loop, without add an if

Tags: c#

I have a loop that is going through each element of a list.

At the moment I have the foreach loop, and inisde, an if that check a variable for the element of the list. If the value is true, I do certain activities, otherwise I move on.

I was wondering if there is some sort of construct, that would allow me to write something like

```
foreach (myclass item in itemlist) where ( item.is_red)
{
     ... do something
}
```

instead than what I have currently

```
foreach (myclass item in itemlist)
{
    if (item.is_red)
        ... do something
}
```

From what I recall, the "where" can be used only as constant definition mechanism, like when defining a specific type of class; so it can't be used in the context that I am presenting here. Am I stuck with the if-else inside the loop as only solution?

Comment: a bit off topic, but you dont need tha `== true` since the ìs_red` already is a boolean. You can just put `if (item.is_red)

Comment: Fair point; it is an old habit to always type comparisons explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx)

```
foreach (myclass item in itemlist.Where(i => i.is_red))
{

    //... do something
}
```

Comment: For some reasons this solution seems the most natural and easy to read for me. Never used LINQ, but by intuition, I think the i is a reference to the item itself, assigned in the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Convert the enumeration to `List` and use the `Where` and `ForEach` LINQ operator:

```
itemlist.Where(t => t.is_red).ToList().ForEach(t => DoSomething(t));
```

or

```
itemlist.Where(t => t.is_red).ToList().ForEach(t => 
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: ForEach is for `List`, not LINQ I think, but since the OP mentions list in the name, this would probably work too

Comment: Thanks for the reply; is there an advantage in converting as you did? I already have a list of objects "myclass". The syntax seems a bit hard to follow

Comment: The first ToList() is necessary when the itemlist is an IEnumerable. In your case, when using an actual List, this would not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could filter what you want iterate with LINQ `Where` in the collection first:

```
foreach (myclass item in itemlist.Where(x => x.is_red)) //here is the `Where`
{
    //do your stuffs
}
```

Comment: You and NAsreddine have the same solution  :) Thanks to you too

Comment: I did upvote yours too; I guess you posted at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Almost :)

```
foreach (var item in (from i in numbers where i.is_red select i))
{
    ... do something
}
```

There generally is a small performance hit when LINQ is used to iterate over lists or arrays, since an enumerator object is to be created.

Another way to tackle your problem is to use your condition as guard clause. This can reduce nesting and complexity and usually improves readability (although there is also the opinion of not using multiple returns/continues/breaks in a function/loop to keep cyclomatic complexity down):

```
foreach (var item in itemlist)
{
    if (!item.is_red) { continue; }

    ... do something
}
```

In the end it probably boils down to company policy/personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Can you elaborate on the performance hit? My list will contain at most 40-50 objects. Not being familiar with LINQ, I do not have metrics based on previous experience, to weight the potential loss in performances.

Comment: Usually, the performance difference is negligible. First write readable code, then write fast code (and only if it's really too slow for your concrete use case).